# How to go back on my app

Tags: android

I want to re-implement the back button for my application..

For example, when the user clicks on the back button of the cellphone the app will move to the last page, and if this page is the first, quit application

I've already tried a lot of solutions that I found on the internet, but none of them worked.

Solutions that i already tried:

```
@Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
             moveTaskToBack(true);
             return true;
         }
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }
```

---

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed ()
    {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
                return;
    }
```

---

the only way that i got sucess is this:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {   
  // Handling the back button
  if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,BtConn.class);
    this.startActivity(i);
    return true;
  } else {
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }
}
```

but it's too slow.

My application is for Android 2.1

------------- edit -------------

Success, but one slow solution

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 

  if ( contentView == R.layout.main){
      Log.d("AQUI", "entro");
      finish();
  }else{
      Log.d("AQUI", "nao entro");
      this.finish();
      Intent i = new Intent(this,BtConn.class);
      this.startActivity(i);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Please explain how the default behavior of the back-button is different from what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Videre> Read the question carefully. Back press does not land the user to the launching activity!!

Answer (score 0):

Catch the back button and call `this.finish();`.

Comment: but this.finish() will end my application,
i wanna go back to the first screen if the application is in other screen

Comment: nope, calling this.finish() will finish the current activity, and go back to the last activity.

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
           Log.d("click","backButtonclicked");
           SingleHouse.this.startActivity(new Intent(SingleHouse.this, RentPage.class));
           moveTaskToBack(false);
           return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

implement this.Here the activity is SingleHouse.I moved back to the first activity called RentPage